# Iterate on a list with a foreign key using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have two tables in my database  `Compte` and  `Respnsable`. In `Compte` table I have a foreign key column "`responsable`".  What I want to do is show Responsable's name in a table of compte in a jsp page.

```
<c:forEach items="${lescompte}" var="compt">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${compt.idCompte}</td>
                            <td>${compt.responsable.name}</td>
                        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

And I have this Error :

> javax.el.ELException: Error reading [name] on type
>   [co.ma.entity.Responsable$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5949c96e]

Class Compte :

```
package co.ma.entity;
// Generated 10 août 2017 21:09:03 by Hibernate Tools 5.2.3.Final

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Compte generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "compte", catalog = "topic")
public class Compte implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idCompte;
    private Responsable responsable;
    private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>(0);

    public Compte() {
    }

    public Compte(Responsable responsable) {
        this.responsable = responsable;
    }

    public Compte(Responsable responsable, Set<Contact> contacts) {
        this.responsable = responsable;
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "Id_Compte", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdCompte() {
        return this.idCompte;
    }

    public void setIdCompte(Integer idCompte) {
        this.idCompte = idCompte;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Id_Respo", nullable = false)
    public Responsable getResponsable() {
        return this.responsable;
    }

    public void setResponsable(Responsable responsable) {
        this.responsable = responsable;
    }
}
```

Class Responsable :

```
package co.ma.entity;
// Generated 10 août 2017 21:09:03 by Hibernate Tools 5.2.3.Final

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Responsable generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "responsable", catalog = "topic")
public class Responsable implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idRespo;
    private String name;
    private Set<Compte> comptes = new HashSet<Compte>(0);

    public Responsable() {
    }

    public Responsable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Responsable(String name, Set<Compte> comptes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.comptes = comptes;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "Id_Respo", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdRespo() {
        return this.idRespo;
    }

    public void setIdRespo(Integer idRespo) {
        this.idRespo = idRespo;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 25)
    public String getname() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "responsable")
    public Set<Compte> getComptes() {
        return this.comptes;
    }

    public void setComptes(Set<Compte> comptes) {
        this.comptes = comptes;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of the relevant classes? Maybe a [Minimum, verifiable, complete example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I add them up .

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you're trying to access a `name` property from foreign key `responsable` which does not exist. Remember foreign keys are just passed on "values", not the "table" itself.

If the foreign key `responsable` is already the name you want to display, then just remove the `.name`.

Otherwise, you might need another `forEach` to match the column `responsable` in `compte` table to the `Respnsable` table. It might look like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${lescompte}" var="compt">
       <tr>
           <td>${compt.idCompte}</td>
           <c:forEach items="${nameOfResponsableTable}" var="resp">
               <c:if test="${compt.responsable == resp.valueToCompare}">
                   <td>${resp.name}</td>
               </c:if>
           </c:forEach>
       </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I hope I understood your problem well and hopefully this helps! :)